# Writing a sequence that adds the summation of Num: Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I write an expression that adds numbers in a sequence to find the summation of num. Num is a positive integer for example:

```
summation(2) -> 3
1 + 2

summation(8) -> 36
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8
```

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
#8(num)+1%2 = 4.5
#4.5* 8 = 36 
# num #=> 36 

def summation(num)
num= num*num +1 % 2 
end
```

and [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55d24f55d7dd296eb9000030/train/ruby) is a link to the kata for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the well-known closed-form formula for the *triangular numbers*: n * (n + 1) / 2

```rb
def summation(num)
  num * (num + 1) / 2
end
```

However, this formula is already implemented by [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) for [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html)s, so this would probably be more readable:

```rb
def summation(num)
  (1..num).sum
end
```

Comment: Legend! thanks for giving two examples of how it can be written

Comment: Is the three dot range a typo?

Comment: @steenslag: I always get them mixed up.